# Can I delete a parent branch?

Tags: version-control, tfs, source-control-explorer

Can safely delete a parent branch? I have a branch structure as follows:

- Branch A

  - Branch B

    - Branch C
    - Branch D

Branch A is redundant & un-needed.  Can I delete it without affecting Branch B & it's children?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you must first [reparent the child branches](http://roadtoalm.com/2012/09/19/reparent-of-a-source-controlled-branch-why-and-how/) so that they have no parent. (to unparent them, parent them to themselves from them commandline). Then you can safely delete the old branch. As long as you do not *destroy* the old branch, your history will also remain available.

In the Merge window your old branch will still show up due to the historical relationship. The only way to remove that relationship is to destroy the data in the deleted branch. (Note that in order to destroy properly, you first need to delete the folder, check it in, and then destroy it. You will need to rebuild the datawarehouse of TFS for the data to update there as well).